# Google Cloud App SDK crash → cloud crashed (LookupError): unknown encoding cp65001

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I get App Engine from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/

After install, I cant run `gsutil init` or  `gcloud info --run-diagnostics` in  Google Clood SDK Shell or Windows Powershell, it ends with this error:

```
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
ERROR: gcloud crashed (LookupError): unknown encoding: cp65001

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

I had UTF-8 set as the encoding:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding
BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

I've tried all this answers, but it didn't help → [gsutil command crashes every time on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221389/gsutil-command-crashes-every-time-on-windows-10),
[LookupError: unknown encoding: cp0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096631/lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp0), [Python 2.7 : LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176270/python-2-7-lookuperror-unknown-encoding-cp65001)

I've tried install Python 3.7, 2.7.9 and "Bundled Python".

Comment: it reads `CodePage: 65001` ...which equals `cp65001`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on Windows 10 and remembered that before Google Cloud installation I had enabled Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide support and disabling that beta feature resolved the issue.

To disable it:

- Open **Region & language settings** (press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> and type: *region*)
- In **Related settings** section click **Administrative language settings**
- On the **Administrative** tab click **Change system locale...**
- Be sure to uncheck **Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support**

Try reinstalling Google Cloud SDK and after execute in command line `gcloud init` again, should work.

**Update**

*This solution considers that you’re using a native shell. If it’s not the case then please try the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018083/7598113) of @jee-mok*.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Didn't have to reinstall Google Cloud SDK (just reboot)

Comment: Company's cloud deployment just got saved:)

Comment: This did not work for me. My "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" setting was already unchecked. There's another answer below this one that worked for me. They were using the integrated VS Code terminal and found that a separate terminal didn't have the issue. This was also the case for me. Separate terminal fixed it.

Comment: Hero, I didn't even think about this having influence. Wow, thank you! It worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

You can try running:

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

Or, create an environment variable with the name 'PYTHONIOENCODING' and value 'UTF-8'.

It solves the problem for me.

Comment: Yes! Solves it for me to! I think it is related to this: https://bugs.python.org/issue1602

Comment: Me too :) Thank you. And how odd that this isn't mentioned anywhere in the official Google docs how to set up UTF-8 output on Windows.

Comment: `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING='UTF-8'` with powershell

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to make reconnection with Google cloud shell.
Reopen Google Cloud SDK Shell

```
gcloud init
```

it will ask for new configuration or use an existing one, I used existing one
then select account
select project on cloud which you want to work.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to issue the deploy via a *separate* powershell window and not the one embedded in Visual Studio Code. Possibly VS Code alters the UTF page settings of the embedded terminal.

BTW, I was deploying a nodeJS app, not a python app.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. I was following the steps in the accepted answer and found that my "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" was already unchecked. Then, I read this and realized I was also using the integrated VS Code terminal. Using a separate Windows terminal to run my gcloud commands instead worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same also when I run that command inside vscode terminal, but when I open another cmd and run the same command everything works perfectly maybe the vscode default terminal is windows powershell